# Java Spark Api GroupBy + fill null fields

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Good day collegues, i coudn't resolve a problem with transformation.

DataSet example:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Col1    Col2    Col3    Col2    Col3 |
+--------------------------------------+
| Value 1 Value 2 123                  |
| Value 1 Value 2         124          |
| Value 1 Value 2                  125 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Needed output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|Col1    Col2    Col3    Col2    Col3                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Value 1 Value 2   123     124     125                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I did it in jupiter with Apache toree and it looks like:

```
val z = spark.read.parquet("/*/*.parquet")
val d = z.groupBy("Col1","Col2").agg(first(col("Col3"),true).as("Col3"),first(col("Col4"),true).as("Col4"),first(col("Col5"),true).as("Col5")))
```

How to do it with Java Spark Api?

Comment: What have you tried using the `Java Spark API` so far? Your provided code so far is only Scala? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I coudn't find the first func in java spark api connected with dataset transformation.

Comment: Are there any more information about (the structure of) the DataSet that you have?

Comment: 5 string fields
scala code works fine, i just wanna do it with common java spark api methods from apache.spark.sql packets.

Comment: So what is not working? Are you asking for a rewrite of your two Scala lines?

Comment: Yes, rewrite using Java.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working the way you expect?

Comment: read
                .groupBy("val1", "val2")
                .agg(new Column("val3").asc_nulls_last(),
                        new Column("val4").asc_nulls_last(),
                        new Column("val5").asc_nulls_last());

Answer (score 0):

find a way do it with Java

```
   private Dataset<RCR> getRCR() {
        Dataset<RCR> read = respCookieRelReader.read(false, inputPath);
        read
                .groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3")
                .agg(functions.first(new Column("col4")).as("col4"),
                        functions.first(new Column("col5")).as("col5"),
                        functions.first(new Column("col6")).as("col6"),
                        functions.first(new Column("col7")).as("col7"));
        return read;
    }
```